# How to render HTML in x-magento-template?

Tags: magento2, javascript, template, x-magento-template

I have used this blog https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-write-javascript-template-in-magento2/ to use **x-magento-template**. In this I can render data using such code:

```
<%- data.name %>
```

But it shows only text data, if I pass HTML, then also it renders it as text. Can someone tell me the solution of it?

Answer (score 4):

`<%= data.name %>`

Magento 2 uses the Underscore.js `template` utility function to compile the `x-magento-javascript` templates. This is handled in `mage/template`. Notice the use of `=` versus `-`. I would recommend taking a look at [their documentation](https://underscorejs.org/#template), where you can find the following:

> Template functions can both interpolate values, using `<%= … %>`, as
>   well as execute arbitrary JavaScript code, with `<% … %>`. If you wish
>   to interpolate a value, and have it be HTML-escaped, use `<%- … %>`.

Comment: <%= data.name %> it works